# Спецификатор final для функции

Tags: c++

При добавлении спецификатора `final` мы запрещаем переопределять метод в базовом классе. Тогда зачем нам нужен в базовом классе создавать виртуальный метод, если можно его оставить обычным? Для чего еще используется виртуальный модификатор?

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething(int x) final;
};
```

Например вот так:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void doSomething(int x);
};
```

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704406/whats-the-point-of-a-final-virtual-function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Такая комбинация `virtual` и `final` будет формально корректной, но фактически бессмысленной. Так что вопрос тут скорее к автору кода: зачем они объявили такой метод?

Если задаться целью попритягивать за уши оправдания для такого использования, то возможной причиной может быть желание формально сделать класс *полиморфным*. (Например, захотелось мне для каких-то моих целей, чтобы `dynamic_cast<void *>` работал с указателями типа `Base *`, а класс `Base *` как назло у меня не является полиморфным.) Для этого надо создать в нем хотя бы один виртуальный метод, даже если виртуальность этого метода на самом деле "никому больше не нужна". Традиционно в таких ситуациях виртуальным делают деструктор. Но в качестве странноватого альтернативного варианта можно рассмотреть и такую "фиктивную" виртуальность, как в вашем примере.

P.S. Не надо называть невиртуальные методы "статическими". Термин *статический метод* в языке С++ уже зарезервирован и используется для совсем других целей.

Answer (score 3):

Стандартом `c++11` спецификатор `final` определяется как `virt-specifier`, поэтому он не имеет смысла для невиртуальных методов и генерирует ошибку:

```
marked final, but is not virtual
```

Однако, как правило, `final` не используется в определении виртуальных методов базового класса.
`final` используется в классах-наследниках, которые переопределяют метод, чтобы предотвратить дальнейшее изменение реализации метода.
Поэтому `final` зачастую используется вместе со спецификатором `override`.

Answer (score 2):

Спецификатор `final` *обычно* не используют в базовом классе (смотри ответ **vp_arth**).

Данный модификатор используется, чтобы запретить переопределение виртуальной функции в классе-наследнике, поэтому *обычно* используется при наследовании более чем на 2 уровня.

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "I'm A!\n"; }
};

struct B : A {
    virtual void foo() override final { std::cout << "I'm B!\n"; }
};

struct C : B {
    virtual void foo() override { std::cout << "I'm C!\n"; } // <- запрещено, ошибка времени компиляции
};
```

P.S. В наследниках ключевое слово `virtual` не несёт смысловой нагрузки, но для наглядности оставил.

Comment: Почему бессмысленно-то? Как иначе запретить переопределять поведение метода уже во втором наследнике? Невиртуальные функции не имеют такого механизма

Comment: @vp_arth перечитал Ваш ответ, понял, согласен. Исправил свой.